# How to cleanly deal with different behavior based on polymorphism 

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, polymorphism

Suppose I have an interface `IFoo` with implementation classes `VideoFoo`, `AudioFoo`, and `TextFoo`.  Suppose further that I cannot modify any of that code.  Suppose that I would then like to write a function that acts differently based on the runtime type of `IFoo`, such as

```
Public Class Bar
    Public Shared Sub Fix(ByVal Foo as IFoo)
        If TypeOf Foo Is VideoFoo Then DoBar1()
        If TypeOf Foo Is AudioFoo Then DoBar2()
        If TypeOf Foo Is TextFoo Then DoBar3()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like to refactor this to use overloaded methods:

```
Sub DoBar(ByVal foo as VideoFoo)
Sub DoBar(ByVal foo as AudioFoo)
Sub DoBar(ByVal foo as TextFoo)
```

But the only way I see to do something like that would be to write

```
Sub DoBar(ByVal foo as IFoo)
```

Then I have to do my "If TypeOf ... Is" again.  How can I refactor this to take advantage of the polymorphism of the implementations of `IFoo` without manually checking the types?

(in VB.NET, though my question applies to C# too)

Comment: Why not have overloads for Fix?

Comment: Because I have an instance of type IFoo; If I just add other overloads to Class Bar, my code will always call Fix(IFoo) rather than the specific Fix(...) that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one option is to simply overload the `Fix()` method so that you have one overload for each type implementing `IFoo`. But I suspect you want to accept the interface directly, rather than it's implementing types.

**What you're actually looking for is [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch).** Normally, C#/VB use the types of the argument(s) to perform overload resolution at compile time, and dynamic dispatch of the call based on the runtime type of the instance on which the method is called. What you want is to *perform overload resolution* at runtime based on the *runtime* types of the arguments - a feature that neither VB.NET or C# directly support.

**In the past, I've generally solved this kind of problem using a dictionary of delegates indexed by `System.Type`:**

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type,Action<IFoo>> _dispatchDictionary;

static Bar()
{
    _dispatchDictionary.Add( typeof(TextFoo),  DoBarTextFoo );
    _dispatchDictionary.Add( typeof(AudioFoo), DoBarAudioFoo );
    _dispatchDictionary.Add( typeof(VideoFoo), DoBarVideoFoo );        
}

public void Fix( IFoo foo )
{
   Action<IFoo> barAction;
   if( _dispatchDictionary.TryGetValue( foo.GetType(), out barAction ) )
   {
      barAction( foo );
   }
   throw new NotSupportedException("No Bar exists for type" + foo.GetType());
}

private void DoBarTextFoo( IFoo foo ) { TextFoo textFoo = (TextFoo)foo; ... }
private void DoBarAudioFoo( IFoo foo ) { AudioFoo textFoo = (AudioFoo)foo; ... }
private void DoBarVideoFoo( IFoo foo ) { VideoFoo textFoo = (VideoFoo)foo; ... }
```

However, as of C# 4, we can now use the `dynamic` keyword in C# do essentially do the same thing (VB.NET does not have this feature as of yet):

```
public void Fix( IFoo foo )
{
    dynamic dynFoo = foo;
    dynamic thisBar = this;

    thisBar.DoBar( dynFoo ); // performs runtime resolution, may throw
}

private void Dobar( TextFoo foo ) { ... /* no casts needed here */ }
private void Dobar( AudioFoo foo ) { ... }
private void Dobar( VideoFoo foo ) { ... }
```

Note that using the `dynamic` keyword this way has a price - it requires that the call site be processed at runtime. It essentially spins up a version of the C# compiler at runtime, processes the metadata captured by the compiler, performs runtime analysis of the types, and spits out C# code. Fortunately, the the DLR can typicall cache such call sites effectively after their first use.

**As a general rule, I find both of these pattern to be confusing, and overkill for most situations.** If the number of subtypes is small and they are all known ahead of time, a simple `if/else` block can bemuch simpler and clearer.

Comment: I don't think multiple dispatch is the answer to this question. Patrick only seems to be switching based on *one* type, not two.

Comment: In fact VB.Net has had runtime resolution from the very first version, provided you use `Option Strict Off`. Most people recommend limiting `Option Strict Off` to as few source files as possible, because there's no direct equivalent to `dynamic` - you can't limit dynamic resolution and implicit casting to specific variables, it applies to an entire source file.

Comment: ... [Requests](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/591963/please-give-vb-net-some-equivalent-for-c-dynamic-with-option-strict-on) for an exact equivalent keyword to `dynamic` in VB.Net are not meeting with [much support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2010/01/28/core2-dynamic-pseudo-type-scoped-late-binding.aspx) from Microsoft :(

Comment: I give you an answer with REAL multiple dispatch BEFORE this guy's answer (which has immitation dispatch and a blatant copy of my anw

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking about is [Multiple Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), or a language feature that allows method overload resolution at runtime instead of compile time.

Unfortunately C# and VB.NET are both single-dispatch languages, which means the method overload is chosen at compile time. This means that the overload for an IFoo object will always be chosen for IFoo, regardless of its implementing type.

There are ways around this however. One way is to use the Visitor design pattern to implement double-dispatch, which would work. In C# you can also use the new `dynamic` keyword to force the run-time environment to resolve the overload at run-time. I wrote a [blog entry](http://blog.martindoms.com/2011/01/04/collision-detection-the-oo-way-with-c-multiple-dispatch/) about how to perform collision handling using this technique, but it's certainly applicable to what you're doing too.

I'm not terribly familiar with VB.NET, but I believe the language exhibits some dynamic behaviours by default, if the objects are cast to Object. Someone please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to avoid dynamic behavior, so my question is the same for C# and VB.NET.

Comment: VB.Net can be used dynamically if you use `Option Strict Off`. I recommend using `Option Strict On` in the majority of your code, and limiting `Option Strict Off` to source files where it's specifically needed for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the interface, nor any of the classes, then it stands to reason that no previously written code can take advantage of this new Fix function you want to add.

I don't know VB.net, but I can't help but wonder why you don't simply sub-class off of each of the current classes (and the interface,) and put your new Fix method in the sub-classes. All of your new code that wants to send the Fix message should accept an IFixFoo instead of an IFoo.

If you want to call Fix on IFoo objects that you didn't create, then you need a method that can create a correct IFixFoo. Using the above, you only have one place where you have to do the `If TypeOf ... Is` (when you actually convert an IFoo to an IFixFoo.