# Polymorphism in VB.Net when dealing with Generics

Tags: .net, vb.net, polymorphism

I have a function called `Modify`. It is delcared like so:

```
Public Function Modify(Of SIMType As {New, DAOBase})(ByVal obj As DAOBase) As Boolean
```

You can see that this function is generic. It takes as a paramer a object that is a DAOBase or subclasses of DAOBase.

Inside the modify function there is a call like so:

```
DAOToGP(obj)
```

This is where the polymorphism comes into play. There are four or so subclasses I have created of `DAOBase`. I have written a `DAOToGP()` for each of these types. So in the `Modify()` function, when it calls the `DAOToGP(obj)`, polymorphism should kick in and it should call the correct implementation of `DAOToGP()` depending on the type that I pass into `Modify()`.

However, I get the following error:

```
Error   20  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DAOToGP' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
'Public Shared Function DAOToGP(distributor As Distributors) As Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.Vendor': Argument matching parameter 'distributor' narrows from 'SierraLib.DAOBase' to 'IMS.Distributors'.
'Public Shared Function DAOToGP(product As Products) As Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.SalesItem': Argument matching parameter 'product' narrows from 'SierraLib.DAOBase' to 'IMS.Products'. C:\Users\dvargo.SIERRAWOWIRES\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SIM\Dev_2\SIM\IMS\DVSIMLib\GP\GPSIMRunner\Runners\RunnerBase.vb 66  39  IMS
```

I am kind of at a loss here. I am not sure why it cant figure out which function to call. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `obj` as `SIMType` instead of `DAOBase`:

```
Public Function Modify(Of SIMType As {New, DAOBase})(ByVal obj As SIMType) As Boolean
```

Otherwise your generic type parameter would be useless.

---

EDIT:

Your DAOToGP function have different signatures and are apparently not derived from a base class. Try this:

```
Public Class DAOBase(Of Tin, Tout)
    Public Function DAOToGP(ByVal obj As Tin) As Tout
    End Function
End Class

Public Module Test_DAOBase
    Public Function Modify(Of Tin, Tout)(ByVal obj As DAOBase(Of Tin, Tout)) As Boolean
    End Function
End Module
```

---

You could also declare DAOBAse as an abstract class (MustInherit) and DAOToGP as an abstract function (MustOverride):

```
Public MustInherit Class DAOBase(Of Tin As {New}, Tout)
    Public MustOverride Function DAOToGP(ByVal obj As Tin) As Tout
End Class

Public Class DAOProduct
    Inherits DAOBase(Of Products, SalesItem)

    Public Overrides Function DAOToGP(ByVal obj As Products) As SalesItem
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class

Public Module Test_DAOBase
    Public Function Modify(Of Tin As {New}, Tout)(ByVal obj As DAOBase(Of Tin, Tout)) As Boolean
        Dim out As Tout = obj.DAOToGP(New Tin())     'This is OK
    End Function

    Public Sub TestModify()
        Dim daoProd = New DAOProduct()
        Modify(daoProd)  'This is OK
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then declare different classes inheriting from `DAOBase` for the different combinations of parameter types (`DAOProduct` in my example).

Comment: The SIMTye gets used a couple of different places in the function. But why does the Overload resolution fail? Why cant it find the correct version of `DAOToGP()` to use

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to perform overload resolution at runtime based on the runtime types of the arguments. But VB overloading is resolved at *compile-time* not *run-time*.  (Unless you use `Option Strict Off`, see later.)

By the way the problem is not related to the use of generics - it would be just the same in a non-generic routine.

The best solution for such a small number of types might be a simple `If` block.

```
If obj Is TypeOf subclassone Then
  Dim obj1 As subclassone
  obj1 = obj
  DAOToGP(obj1)
ElseIf obj Is TypeOf subclasstwo Then
  Dim obj2 As subclasstwo
  obj2 = obj
  DAOToGP(obj2)
  'and so on...
```

Or you could use an [array of delegates indexed by System.Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425420/15639) as seen in this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425228/how-to-cleanly-deal-with-different-behavior-based-on-polymorphism)

An alternative is to use `Option Strict Off` and then write

```
Dim objWhatever As Object
objWhatever = obj
DAOToGP(obj)  ' resolved at runtime, might Throw
```

But I **don't recommend this** because `Option Strict Off` disables some very useful compiler checks.