# Function Template(of T as numeric)?

Tags: vb.net, polymorphism

I wish to make a polymorph function that uses the usual arithmetic functions on the input, which is a double or an integer. Example:

```
public function Plus(of T )(a as T, b as T) as T
    return a+b
end function
```

Obviously this cannot work : T does not always implement the + operator.

I tried:
    (of T as numeric)
    (of T = double, integer )

all those are obviously wrong.

this does not work either:

```
public function Plus(of T )(a as T, b as T) as double
    return CType(a, Double)+CType(b, Double)
end function
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!

PS: I will also need this T to be iComparable, for example:

```
public function PlusStupid(of T as icomparable(of T))(a as T, b as T) as T
    return a*a+b*b + (a-b) * a.CompareTo(b) 
    'returns a²+b²+ b-a if a<b
    'returns a²+b²+ a-b if a>b
    'returns a²+b²  if a=b
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it manually:

```
Public Function Plus(of T As IComparable)(a As T, b As T) As T
    Try
        Return a+b
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Function
```

I don't really know `how to check if a class has overridden the + operator` in VB.Net, so I put it in a Try/Catch expecting it to fail if it doesn't exist...

**EDIT**

After testing and reading, I saw that `(Of T As IComparable)` is valid (I didn't know that before today, thanks comments).

Comment: for icomparable, best is to use (of T as icomparable(of T) ) . This does not compile correctly.

Comment: Does `IComparable` guarantee the implementation of + operator?

Comment: @dotNET : no it does not, but in the real code I also need to use " a>B" or equivalently "a.compareto(b)=1"

Comment: @SsJVasto : Please be aware that (of T as icomparable) is totally useless : you can compare to nothing. You should use (of T as icomparable(of T))

Comment: @Pierre What's wrong with `Compare(1, Nothing) --> False`?

Comment: @SsJVasto :  I mean that you cannot use the fact that T is icomparable if you can compare it to no type. For example if you write A.compareto(b) , you will get an error.

Comment: @Pierre Are you sure that the function will be called?  if b is `NoType`, then it is clearly not `T`.  There would be a problem if the definition was `Public Function Plus(Of T As IComparable, Of U As IComparable)(a As T, b As U) As T`

Comment: @SsJVasto : in that case you can use (of T as icomparable(of S), S)(a As T, b As U) and then a.compareto(b) will work nicely. I use it a lot! All I mean is that there is no possible way writing (of T as icomparable) can let you do something useful that (of T)  cannot do

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround! Thanks to [Polymorphism in VB.Net when dealing with Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761039/polymorphism-in-vb-net-when-dealing-with-generics?rq=1)

```
public function PlusStupid(of T as {IComparable(Of T), IConvertible})(a as T, b as T) as T
    return a.ToDouble(nothing)+b.ToDouble(nothing) +   a.CompareTo(b) 
end function
```

For now it seems to work. However this means I **HAVE TO make a cast**, which is not my first intent: not true polymorphism, there is double written. I leave the question open for a better solution.

Comment: well, be sure to upvote the original if it helped with your issue